# How to access callback object data inside custom tooltip created with Div()?

Tags: python, html, bokeh

As an extension of [Bokeh TapTool running custom JS and tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQxbQ.png), I would like to add dynamic links to the custom HTML template I use for a map application that uses the custom tooltip in the referred question. This application in Bokeh shows a map with different sets of circles, and when you click one of them the TapTool shows a small popup with 3 rows (running JS code and using a custom HTML template), like this:

[image]

The first and second rows are hyperlinks, the first is internal to other url inside the application, and the second one is an external http link. Both links work, with the link dynamically changed using each circle related information. Below the custom template:

```
<div style="width: 300px;">
              <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #26aae1; display: inline-block; text-align: right;">Site ID:</div>    
              <div style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; text-align: left; text-decoration: underline;">              
                  <a href="http://10.224.45.213:8060/sitedb/site_detail_info/@site_id"> {{ siteidtest }} </a>    
              </div>        
              <div style="font-size: 12px; display: block;"></div>

              <div style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; color: #26aae1; text-align: right;">RFNSA ID: </div>
              <div style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; text-decoration: underline;">
                  <a href="https://www.rfnsa.com.au/@site_rfnsa_id/detail" target="_blank"> 
                    <div style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; text-decoration: underline;"> "@site_rfnsa_id" </div> 
                  </a>
              </div>            
              <div style="font-size: 12px; display: block;"></div>


              <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #26aae1; text-align: right; display: inline-block;">Milestone completed: </div>
              <div style="font-size: 12px; color: black; display: inline-block; text-align: left;"> @site_milestone_number - </div>
              <div style="font-size: 12px; color: black; display: inline-block; text-align: left;"> @site_status </div>
              <div style="font-size: 12px; display: block;"></div>              
          </div>
```

The reference to @site_id and @site_rfnsa_id inside the href attribute works well, using the values corresponding to the clicked circle (and updated by a JS callback), but the same references @site_id and @site_rfnsa_id inside the link texts do not work, as seen in the first image above. The references to @site_milestone_number and @site_status work as well, inside div tags. I am trying different things, apart from using @site_id or @site_rfnsa_id in the text (with and without ""), like using jQuery or script tags inside the  text, but nothing works so far. My knowledge of HTML and scripts is very limited, and I have no idea what else to try.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: That's difficult in this case. I have found a workaround by duplicating the variables I want to use in the template. It is as if once used, they are erased and can't be referenced anymore.

Comment: That's only because the code that you use does it that way, that's why I asked for an MRE. It may be hard to come up with it, but without it it's just impossible to provide any help.

Comment: I know it's entirely a fault in my code, but the code belongs to an app that works within Django (with many other apps) and is connected to a MySQL remote database. It's quite time consuming to produce a MRE in this case, but thank you for your interest. I will just duplicate the variables until I can refine my code.